# Minimum Visual Studio Version for Visual studio 2015 solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, sln-file

I have upgraded a project from VS 2013 to VS 2015. Everything works great, I can now open the same Project in both VS 2013 and VS 2015.

Now, with this new Roslyn compiler of VS 2015, I assume that when I introduce some new C# 6 features in the Project, I will be able to open the Project only in VS 2015.(In 2013 I will get some compiler errors)

What would be the `MinimumVisualStudioVersion` to enter in the .sln file, until now I was able to open the solution in VS 2013, VS 2012 and also VS 2010:

```
# Visual Studio 2013
VisualStudioVersion = 12.0.40629.0
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
```

This means that it was possible to open VS2013 Projects in VS 2010 without Problems.

But, with the new compiler features of 2015, does that mean that the `MinimumVisualStudioVersion` has to be >= to `14.x.xxxxx.x` for VS 2015 Projects?

Comment: Is there another question behind this? Obviously you can't use a VS2015 compiler in previous versions. Do you want to block older versions from opening the project? In this case you could even set 14.0.0.0. On the other hand, VS probably does for you already

Comment: Changing the *solution's* version though, isn't the best idea because you may have a lot of compatible projects but only a few that require VS2015

Comment: The idea is that previously I had a VS 2013 project which could have been opened with VS 2012 and also VS 2010 without problems. Now, if I open it it VS 2015 and use the new compiler features, I will not be able to open it in previous VS versions.

Answer (score 2):

This means that the minimum version of Visual Studio to open this solution is **10.0.40219.1** which is actually **Visual Studio 2010 SP1**.

Comment: I know what the **MinimumVisualStudioVersion** means, but the question is it would make sense to set another **MinimumVisualStudioVersion** (<14.x.xxxxx.x) if the .sln **VisualStudioVersion == 14.x.xxxxx.x**